# Customizing jQuery validate to pop-up error message over an icon

Tags: validation, jquery-selectors, jquery-validate, traversal, qtip

This might be a fundamental jQuery misunderstanding but I've got to ask...

I'm trying to get the jQuery.validate to display its error messages on qTip, a jQuery plugin for customizing tooltips.  Specifically I want to get the tooltip to pop-up on mouseover of a little red "X" icon.

I can get the tooltip to popup over the form field using the following code:

```
$().ready(function() {
    // validate signup form on keyup and submit
    $("#signup").validate({
                errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    element.parent().parent().append('<div class="rederrorx"></div>');
                    element.qtip(
                    {
                        //qTip formatting and content code
                    });
        },
```

But to get the tooltip to pop up over a red x, I change `element.qTip(` to `$(".rederrorx").qTip(` and it doesn't work (no message/qTip initialized).

Has the concept of selectors just gone way over my head?  Prob so.  Or is the jQuery class selector not selecting anything because the `append` has yet to take place?  Or...

Thanks!
Emile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced `element.parent()` with `element.parents('.classname')` in order to pinpoint the exact parent element I wanted.  I'm assuming a plugin added nested divs without telling me.  No other answers....

lo siento for the stupid question